# How to print an ArrayList<Point>

Tags: java, arraylist

Generally ArrayList will print nicely with a primitive type. I need to print out an ArrayList cleanly, like it does with primitive types. Right now it gives me this:

`[java.awt.Point[x=8,y=8], java.awt.Point[x=7,y=9], java.awt.Point[x=6,y=8]`...

I just need to print it without "java.awt.Point", the details I'm not so worried about. I'm not sure if I can do this with a loop, targeting the index of the arrayList or...

This is the code I have, it makes a "robot" move around a grid:

```
ArrayList<Point> moves = new ArrayList<Point>();

// code that moves it one square at a time 
// and then add the move to an array 

moves.add(new Point(this.getX(),this.getY()));  // makes a new point, adds it to the array
```

And then to print:

```
System.out.println("Robot 1 moves: "+r1.moves);
```

I'm totally open to different solutions if anyone has a better idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you override your toString method?

Comment: @KickButtowski Assuming that `Point` is the `java.awt.Point` class, extending it to just override it's `toString` method is a poor reason to extend the class.  Better to write a formatting/helper to format the `String` the way you want it.  This way you could have any number of formatter methods, one for each day of the week, depending on your needs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an enhanced `for loop`...

```
for (Point p : r1.moves) {
    System.out.println(p.x + "x" + p.y);
}
```

Take a look at [The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) (it's towards the bottom) for more details

Comment: This is perfect! I knew there must be a simple way to do it - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to either create your own Point object (edit: MadProgrammer fairly chastises me for not pointing out that you should have a *bunch* of other good reasons to extend or replace a built-in class in addition to just a custom toString() method), in which case you could override the toString() method, or create a helper method that'll create a well-formed string from your collection of Points.

For example:

```
public string MakeNicePointsString(ArrayList<Point> points)
{
    String pointsString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length(); i++)
    {
        pointsString += "x=" + points[i].x.toString() + "y=" + points[i].y.toString();
    }

    return pointsString;
}
```

Comment: Extending a class simply to modify it's `toString` method is a really poor reason for extending the object.  Instead of trying to "change" the object, write a helper class/method that formats it the way you.  Who knows, you might need the original `toString` result for something else....IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Fair point - it's not what I'd do, and you're damn right that creating extensions of built-in objects for trivial reasons is dumb dumb dumb. I've updated the post with your disclaimer.

Comment: Nicer :) and you could provide any number of helpers to meet different circumstances ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, I rarely tend to replace them. The only recent case I could think of is that the C# Rectangle has X, Y, Width, and Height, but my use case called for querying the bottom and right coordinates a lot, so I just made my own BoundingRectangle object. Other than that I rarely find reason to extend the built-ins.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 solution:

```
    moves.stream().forEach((p)-> System.out.print("[" + p.x +"," + p.y + "]"));
```

Full example:

```
    List<Point> lst = new ArrayList<Point>();
    lst.add(new java.awt.Point(1,2));
    lst.add(new java.awt.Point(1,8));
    lst.add(new java.awt.Point(7,2));
    lst.add(new java.awt.Point(6,6));
    System.out.print("[");
    lst.stream().forEach((p)-> System.out.print("[" + p.x +"," + p.y + "]"));
    System.out.print("]");
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[1,2][1,8][7,2][6,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the toString method of the Point class, such that it prints the x & y coordinates.

Comment: Since drukle already said the same thing, this isn't adding anything new, also extending a class simply to modify it's `toString` method is a really poor reason for extending the object.  Instead of trying to "change" the object, write a helper class/method that formats it the way you.  Who knows, you might need the original `toString` result for something else....IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I know it is another kind of extending @MadProgrammer ;) because it is defining an annonymous inner class, but you can define an inline overriding for toString method like this :

```
Point p = new Point(10, 20){
     @Override
     public String toString(){
        return (getX() + ", "+ getY()) + "";
     }
};

System.out.println(p); // 10.0, 20.0
```

**this works for this instance only**